# AlarmManager issues when connected to WiFi

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-pendingintent, android-broadcast, android-alarms

I'm using AlarmManager with .setExact on Android 4.4.2 (Device: Danew Dslide 710) to send a PendingIntent to a BroadcastReceiver.

**Works fine** as long as the device is **not connected to WiFi** or **screen is ON**.

When **connected to WiFi** the PendingIntent arrives at the BroadcastReceiver only when screen is ON, or **delayed at the moment the screen get's unlocked**.

I've no idea how WiFi connection effects the AlarmManager?

Any ideas are highly appreciated!